# DB Transaction Laravel not rolling back

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel DB facade to rollback my database transactions if a certain condition is met. But my rollback is not working.

First I started my DB transaction with  `DB::beginTransaction();`

Secondly, I wrote my queries to create the following :

1. Create a new payment batch
2. Create payment batch record
3. Create payment approval
4. Create payment approvers

Thirdly I then did some condition to know when to rollback or commit my DB transactions. But the rollback is not working. Example this block of condition was met in my code but never rollback

```
if(!$mail_status){
   DB::rollBack();
    return back()->with('error', 'Mail not send to approvers. Try again or contact system administrator.');
}
```

Below is the full block of code.

```
//Start transaction
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try{

        //Run Queries

        //Create a new payment batch
        $batch = Batch::create([
            'uuid' => uniqid(),
            'batch_name' => $batch_config->batch_name,
            'service_code' => Auth::user()->service_code,
            'created_by' => Auth::user()->name,
        ]);

        //Create parameters for new payment batch record
        foreach($batch_record_config as $data){
            $record[] = [
                'batch_id' => $batch->batch_id,
                'payee_name' => $data['payee_name'],
                'bank_id' => $data['bank_id'],
                'bank_name' => $data['bank_name'],
                'account_type' => $data['account_type'],
                'account_number' => $data['account_number'],
                'amount' => $data['amount'],
                'description' => $data['description'],
                'year' => date("Y"),
                'month' => date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), 10)),
                'uuid' => uniqid(),
                'service_code' => Auth::user()->service_code,
                'created_at' => now(),
                'created_by' => Auth::user()->name,
            ];
        }
        $batch_record_status = DB::table('batch_record')->insert($record);

        //Generate new payment approval
        $payment_approval = PaymentApproval::create([
            'uuid' => uniqid(),
            'batch_id' => $batch->batch_id,
            'service_code' => Auth::user()->service_code,
            'created_by' => Auth::user()->name,
            'deleted' => 0,
        ]);

        //Generate payment approvers for the payment approval
        $payment_approvers = [];
        foreach($approval_users as $data){
            $payment_approvers[] = [
                'uuid' => uniqid(),
                'payment_approval_id' => $payment_approval->id,
                'approval_user_id' => $data->id,
                'approval_level_id' => $data->approval_level_id,
                'batch_id' => $batch->batch_id,
                'approval_position_value' => $data->approval_level->approval_position,
                'approval_level_name' => $data->approval_level->approval_level,
                'user_id' => $data->user_id,
                'batch_name' => $batch->batch_name,
                'service_code' => Auth::user()->service_code,
                'approved' => 0,
                'deleted' => 0,
                'created_at' => now(),
                'created_by' => Auth::user()->name,
            ];
        }
        $payment_approvers_status = DB::table('payment_approvers')->insert($payment_approvers); 


        // If DB transcation is successful.
        if($batch && $batch_record_status && $payment_approval && $payment_approvers_status){

            //get the next approvers
            $next_approvers = $this->next_approvals($payment_approval->id);

            if($next_approvers){
                //send mail to the next approvers
                $mail_status = $this->send_approvers_mail($next_approvers,$batch);
                if(!$mail_status){
                    DB::rollBack();
                    return back()->with('error', 'Mail not send to approvers. Try again or contact system administrator.');

                }else{
                    DB::commit();
                    return back()->with('success', 'Batch has being initialized');
                }
            }else{
                DB::rollBack();
                return back()->with('error', 'Approvers not found. Try again or contact system administrator.');
            }  

        }else{
            DB::rollBack();
            return back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong. Try again.');
        }



    }catch(\Exception $e){
        DB::rollBack();
        dd($e);
        return back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong... Contact system administrator. Thanks.');
    }
```

Comment: You need to commit `DB::commit();` at the last and use `DB::beginTransaction(); ` inside of the try section

Comment: There is a DB::commit(); inside the condition that checks if the mail is successful. I have also tried to include the DB::beginTranscation(); inside the try-catch but did not work either.

Comment: The `DB::beginTransaction` call doesn't need to be inside the try/catch block, don't worry about that. Which rollback is the one not working?

Comment: All rollbacks are not working. I'm even more interested if the mail is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your and as others have rightly pointed you need to commit the transactions. Which i can't see in your code. There are basically two ways of using transactions which i am aware of.
1.

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);
        DB::table('posts')->delete();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $count = 0;
        \DB::rollBack();
        \Log::info(self::LOG_PREFIX . 'Some Msg ', [$e->__toString()]);
    }

    \DB::commit();
```

2.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
        DB::table('users')->update(['votes' => 1]);
        DB::table('posts')->delete();
    });
```

If you're using second method you won't have to do any commit, this will be rolled back automatically on failure.

I persume the error is in this line of yours 
*$next_approvers = $this->next_approvals($payment_approval->id);*
I couldn't find *next_approvals8 property defined in your code, Plus you're using both Laravel ORM and Raw Statements  (PaymentApproval::create & DB::table('batch_record')->insert($record);)

Try sticking to 1 and see if this works.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention that either your DB get commit or throw some error?.Check what are you getting in mail function response. I thin you got success in mail because your else condition is not execute any case.